# Can read query cause row lock contention in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, concurrency, locking, database-performance

I am working in a high transaction financial system. We have a table that is undertaking a massive number of transaction updates concurrently. All queries are optimized and data models are structured to support concurrency flexibly.

One of the peculiar things that I have noticed is that during the updates if we run a query that runs a `SUM(balance)` function on multiple rows, the AWR report shows that 57% of DB time was spent in row lock contention.

Based on what I read in Oracle locking documentation, no reads can ever acquire locks on rows and can read committed data safely. Would it be the case that if one of the rows that need to be part of `SUM` function has been locked by `Select for Update` statement, the read query would need to wait until lock is released?

Without the read query, the transactions sail through with contention as low as 6%. Is it possible that read queries tend to be CPU intensive and causes contention due to CPU starvation?

I did notice that when we are running read query during operation, the CPU rises from 20% to 80% average.

Comment: The CPU usage increase is probably not related to lock contention. Rather, your query is not only a "read" query, it is also an **aggregate** query, where you **group by** something. THAT is a CPU-intensive operation, while simple reading (without aggregation) and simple insert, update, delete etc. are not CPU-intensive.

Comment: Oracle uses a `consistent read` mechanism to restore the data to the state at the beginning of the query. If there is a lot of changes to be reverted, it could have a CPU impact - see e.g. [OraPub White Paper](http://blog.orapub.com/20110623/impact-of-oracle-database-consistent-reads.html).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first, is your "read query" a `SELECT FOR UPDATE`?  If so, then, *yes* this will cause locking.  `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is effectively a DML, not just a `SELECT`.  It will do row-level locks, and can cause contention.

If your `SELECT` is just that, and not a `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, then it will *never* cause or be blocked by row-level locks.

A related thought, though you didn't mention it, if you're querying a table under heavy DML activity, you may see the query performance degrade, relative to the query performance when the heavy DML is not happening, and that would (likely) be due to Oracle's read consistency mechanism, and the extra work that Oracle may have to do to get a read consistent view of the data.  (Rolling back blocks to a given point in time.)

Comment: Select for update is the locking DML. The read query is the aggregate function query that calls Sum on several rows.

Comment: Ok...so, did I answer your question?  Are you not clear on any or all of it?

Comment: Thanks. It answers my question only partially. Based on your answer I understand that a read query will not cause a row to lock. However my observation is that when the reads increase on the table under heavy DML operations, then contention increases quickly. Without the read query the contention is very low. If read will truly not obtain locks and without read the contention is low, what could be a possible reason for increased contention with merely a change in read frequency?

Comment: That does not make sense.  How are you monitoring the level of contention?  Are you familiar with a tool called snapper?  It's a free script by my friend, Tanel Poder.  https://blog.tanelpoder.com/snapper/  It would be interesting to see a 30 second sample from when the read load is running, and when it's not, with the same DML load.

Comment: I am using Oracle AWR reports generated for hourly snapshots. This is a result of a performance test that I run at a varying transactions per second throughput. At an xxx TPS the row lock contention in awr report is at 5% of db time. Whereas with higher reads, the contention goes up to 58% of DB time. The only difference between the two performance run is a config that enables more read via an aggregate query.

Comment: @Priyank, make sure you got the jist of what previous posters have said: 1. A "SELECT" does not cause a row lock. 2. A "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" *does* take a row level lock. So, the more "select ... for updates" the more chance of contention. So you need to make sure your transactions the acquire the lock run as fast as possible.